# Authenticate Google Admin in Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication, service-accounts

I am trying to authenticate a Google Admin SDK using [`ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json()`](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/service_account.py#L423). I am using the Google Cloud Platform to run a Cloud Function. The Cloud Function gets a file from Cloud Storage, decrypts it, then uses that file to authenticate the service. According to [this](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html) I can authenticate using `from_json_keyfile_name`. I wont have a direct path though so I attempted to authenticate with the contents of the file from `Google Console -> API -> Download credentials`. That json has the following keys:

- type
- project_id
- private_key_id
- private_key
- client_email
- client_id
- auth_uri
- token_uri
- auth_provider_x509_cert_url
- client_x509_cert_url

However, [`ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json()`](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/service_account.py#L423) looks for `_private_key_pkcs12`. which is not in the downloaded json.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what is the issue and what are you trying to accomplish. Could you give some more details on what is the problem you're running into?

Comment: @Maxim Sure. Basically, I need to create a Service Account for Google Admin using json. Not a json file, but actual json. This is possible with `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json()` but it excepts data like `_private_key_pkcs12` which is not found in the json file downloaded from Google Console.

Answer (score 1):

[oauth2client is deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html). Use [google.oauth2.service_account](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html).

Example

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(sa_json)
return build(service_name, service_version, credentials=credentials)
```